# Random seeding seg fault

Tags: c, debugging, error-handling, segmentation-fault

I am asked to put a random seeding into a program that is called when a user types in -r. It is shown to look like

```
-r1234567
```

So as a global variable I set Random = 1234567.

I added this to the top of my function as well:

```
printf("Seed: %d\n", Random);
srand48(Random);
```

Every time I use -r1234567 My program segfaults and says this:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
____strtol_l_internal (nptr=0x0, endptr=0x0, base=10, group=<optimized out>, 
loc=0x7ffff7ad8020) at ../stdlib/strtol_l.c:298
298 ../stdlib/strtol_l.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) bt
#0  ____strtol_l_internal (nptr=0x0, endptr=0x0, base=10, group=<optimized out>, 
loc=0x7ffff7ad8020) at ../stdlib/strtol_l.c:298
#1  0x00007ffff77589e0 in atoi (nptr=<optimized out>) at atoi.c:28
#2  0x0000000000401d8c in getCommandLine (argc=6, argv=0x7fffffffe238)
at prog.c:171
#3  0x0000000000401514 in main (argc=6, argv=0x7fffffffe238) at prog.c:35
(gdb) up
#1  0x00007ffff77589e0 in atoi (nptr=<optimized out>) at atoi.c:28
28  atoi.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) up
#2  0x0000000000401d8c in getCommandLine (argc=6, argv=0x7fffffffe238)
at prog.c:171
warning: Source file is more recent than executable.
```

In my command like: the case looks like this:

```
 while ((c = getopt(argc, argv, "g:n:a:h:s:d:v:r")) != -1)

case 'r': Random = atoi(optarg);       break;
```

So a user wants to to randomize using a seed. They do ./program -r1234567. This then goes into the two lines of code that I put above and should randomize.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please show a more complete example, like showing what `Random` is and how it's declared/defined, and possible assigned. It would be best if you made a small but complete example, also known as a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). You might also want to edit your question to include a complete backtrace from the debugger.

Comment: I added the bt and tried to explain it some more.

Comment: In the debugger, when you're at the frame #2 (i.e. in the `getCommandLine` function) try printing the value of `optarg`. Or maybe add a `printf` call before calling `atoi` to see the actual value of `optarg`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is the `getopt` call, in that you forgot to tell `getopt` that the `-r` argument takes a value:

```
getopt(argc, argv, "g:n:a:h:s:d:v:r:")
/*                                 ^ */
/*                                 | */
/*                    Add colon here */
```

Because of that, the `optarg` pointer is `NULL` when you call `atoi`.

Comment: @user081608 Take this as a lesson to always post, if possible, a more complete example. :) If you haven't done so, I recommend you read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist), it will help you write better questions in the future.

Answer (score 0):

you are giving -r1234567 from the command line , How you are parsing it and giving ito atoi ?

if atoi get "1234567" as its argument then there should not be any problem .. Can you paste the logic which parses the argv[1] ?

Comment: I dont want to add all my code but I added the while loop to look for the case

Comment: The problem is .. you are missing ":" at the end of argument r ...because of this NULL is being passed to atoi .. try adding ":" at the end of r in the getopt !!

Answer (score 0):

Are declaring Random as an int?. srand48 takes a long as an argument so you should be usuing atol instead of atoi:

```
long Random = 42;
printf("Seed: %d\n", Random);
srand48(Random);
```

Comment: So for case 'r': Random = atoi(optarg); I make atoi -> atol?

Comment: @user081608 That should not matter. The compiler will make an implicit cast to `long int` when you call `srand48`.

Comment: I get the warning format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘long int’

Answer (score 0):

The problem is .. you are missing ":" at the end of argument r ...because of this NULL is being passed to atoi .. try adding ":" at the end of r in the getopt !!